# Will I be able to install Ubuntu TV as a shell?

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments, ubuntu-tv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu TV and different desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94149/ubuntu-tv-and-different-desktop-environments)

So how is Ubuntu TV going to be used? I guess it won't be just an application since it will be used as an entire shell on the TV.

It would be really awesome if it really is a shell so that I can choose it on log in from a list of other desktop environments! That way you can build a custom HTPC with Ubuntu TV if you wanted to! So my question is, will Ubuntu TV be a desktop environment?